# make file: header including another header C++

Tags: c++, makefile

I have 3 files

```
main.cpp
a.h
b.h
```

main.cpp includes both a.h and b.h
b.h includes a.h

could anyone explain me how should I write a make file for this?

Is this correct?

```
objects = main.o 
sources = main.cpp

myProj: $(objects) 
    g++ -o myProj $(objects)

main.o: a.h b.h 


$(objects): $(sources)
    g++ -c $(sources)

clean:
    rm $(objects) myProj
```

I dont know how to specify the dependency of b.h on a.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since headers are always compiled as part of .c/.cpp file, there is no need to specify header-to-header dependency. The dependency that you have specified already is sufficient, because `main.cpp` will recompile when a.h and/or b.h change.

Comment: so my make file is correcct??

Comment: @user1344389 Yes, I think it's correct. You can check that the dependencies are OK by modifying one or both headers, and checking if it triggers a recompile; it should.

Comment: @user1344389 It might be educational to read about [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to improve your makefile. For example, in stead of `g++ -o myProj $(objects)` it would be better to use `g++ -o $@ $^`

Answer (score 1):

If you are at all any more confused on makefile concepts, I would recommend checking out this helpful tutorial.

http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html